# Playstore APK different from Signed APK?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk

Good day.

My question today is the following:

If I installed my app from the google playstore then tried to update it manually with an updated signed APK generated straight from android studio would it throw an error?

Does google play add extra meta-data to my app upon submission in which it can only be updated through google play?

My reasons for asking this question are due to my own observations and are stated in the following.

I recently published my app to the app store (my first app). Afterwards I immediately began working on an update the update is ready but this is where things get complicated. I installed my app from google play and then attempted to update it through a signed apk directly from android studio.

The update ran successful however the first screen runs (splash screen nothing special) then it launches the second screen which retrieves data from the database. When it lands on the second screen my app crashes.

I tried the following install patterns:

- Installing a direct older version apk which was not submitted to the play store then the new apk (both are signed) which resulted in success.
- I installed the new updated apk independent of the old apk (by removing the old version) which resulted in success.

From attempting these two scenarios it is certain my code is working properly so the issue must be related to installing an apk from google play as well as a new version not from google play.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your app crashes, logcat will tell you why. You should include that information in your question.

Comment: Indeed it logcat would tell me but I was installing the signed apk independent of android studio.

Comment: logcat works no matter where the app is installed from.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to resolve the error and figure it out. Your answer would be marked as the solution as it answered my primary question. Turns out a method in my database model was being called infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Google Play cannot change anything in your uploaded APK as **Google Play does not have your signing key.** The fact that you're able to install a new version of the APK signed by your key confirms that the key is the same and the app is exactly as you uploaded it.